# Visual Studio and Git: One solution with several projects in own repo, how?

Tags: git

At the moment my company is using VS2015/VS2017 and Microsoft TFS (Team Foundation Server) as source control. It's very common for us to have one solution with several projects added.
If I am working on a added project in my solution, the TFS checks it out to me.

I am trying to do the same using Git as source control. Each project lives in separate Git repos. The problem is that the VS2017 Git plugin does not detect that the added projects are under Git source control. This is very bad since I loose a lot of options. 
I have found one plugin that seems to be able to fix the problem partly.
One big repo is not an option since all the added projects are common modules.

How do You deal with this issue?

Best regards, Brian

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Visual Studio.  Can it not support multiple open projects, each with its own version control?  If it can't support this, then it is a VS limitation and not a Git one.

Comment: When you add a project to a solution all it does is it adds a path of the project in the .sln-file. What I do is I never edit "child projects" from the main projects Visual Studio instance. I open all the projects I need to edit in separate Visual Studios. That way the version control also works on all of those projects.